# What qualifies as a "boat" or an "automobile"?

Tags: meaning

Are all crafts that travel on water considered "boats," even barges, yachts, canoes, rafts, etc?

Are all motor vehicles considered "automobiles," even trucks, semis, and motorcycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No in both cases. A "boat" is something small in size compared to a barge, ship, freighter and implies an appropriate form of propulsion. Certainly not steam, as with a large vessel, and probably not with a pole (or high hopes), as with a raft. Informally, I hear some people use boat to mean any sort of vessel. I usually wonder if the speaker doesn't know the difference or perhaps is making a small joke.

An automobile is personal, passenger-oriented transportation, also something small relative to other types. The term doesn't include busses, trucks, or motorized bicycles. "Vehicle" is the all-encompassing term.

Comment: "I hear some people use boat to mean any sort of vessel. I usually wonder if the speaker doesn't know the difference or perhaps is making a small joke." I don't think these people are making a joke.  Most people just happily call all sea vessels boats informally.

Comment: I disagree. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steamboat foe example

Comment: @trideceth12 - fair enough. Having been born quite a few years after the last steamboat was made, I didn't think of one.

Answer (score 1):

Depends who you are asking - to a sailor there are a huge range of distinctions, especially when it comes to sailing (wind powered).

In the navy everything is a ship except submarines which are boats.

Comment: In the Navy not everything but a sub is a ship. There is also the *launch* or *motor launch*.

Comment: But they don't have names so they don't count

Comment: Just to clarify, would the navy consider -eg- a prindle/hobie cat, a laser, an optimist or similar light craft/dinghies a ship? It doesn't feel correct to do so (at least to me).

Comment: @Basic- I think if you can't put guns on it they don't care about it!

Answer (score 1):

In general, a boat is defined as a vessel which can be carried by a ship - So boat covers everything from small dinghys through some yachts - but this can be quite subjective. An oil tanker could never be considered a boat and a dinghy could never be considered a ship - In between is a somewhat grey area.

There are also special considerations eg hovercraft - which use the same navigation lights as an aircraft and are neither ships nor boats.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. It has a definite answer (no) because not EVERYTHING that  is a sea going craft is a boat. Hovercraft, water-skis, wind-surfing boards, sea-planes, etc., whilst able to move on water are definitely not boats. Motorcycles, semi-trailers, etc., are also not automobiles which are small enclosed passenger vehicles.  However the categories seem not to be very clearly defined (for example is a small goods-van an automobile?). I feel like this is an area of English taxonomy that is lacking.

On a related note, there is a lack of English words to describe the operators of categories of vehicles. "Motorist" applies only to drivers of automobiles (I am not aware of any catch-all term for operators of road vehicles), and "pilot" can refer to people operating planes, ships, even cranes. In aviation a pilot is the "driver" of the aircraft, in shipping a pilot is a guide, on rail a pilot prevents collisions. There are obviously no clear cut categories.